# How do I run gulp eslint continuously and automatically while fixing files -- how to set up watch

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, eslint

I am trying eslint with gulp.  I have set up a task like this:

```
            gulp.task('lint', function () {
                return gulp.src([
            'components/myjs.js'

                                 ])
                    // eslint() attaches the lint output to the eslint property 
                    // of the file object so it can be used by other modules. 
                    .pipe(eslint())
                    // eslint.format() outputs the lint results to the console. 
                    // Alternatively use eslint.formatEach() (see Docs). 
                    .pipe(eslint.format())
                    // To have the process exit with an error code (1) on 
                    // lint error, return the stream and pipe to failOnError last. 
                    .pipe(eslint.failOnError());
            });
```

when I run `gulp lint`
It tells me a lot of errors.  Now I am trying to fix them one by one.  But I have to re-run `gulp lint` manually for it to give me an updated report.  How do I set it up so that it will automatically re-run every time I update `'components/myjs.js'`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add a watch task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('components/myjs.js', ['lint']);
});
```

This way Gulp will track any changes on your `'components/myjs.js'` and execute your `'lint'` task on any change

If you want further reading:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/automate-your-tasks-easily-with-gulp-js

Comment: Thanks!! Now I just run gulp watch.